# setting a default union member

Tags: c++

i'm using templated unions to both assure myself that i always get a 64-bit field for pointers (even on 32-bit machines since there is transmission of data to a 64-bit machine occurring) and to save both the user and myself casting.

```
template <typename type> union lrbPointer
{
    uint64_t intForm;
    type ptrForm; //assumed that type is a pointer type
};

//usage
lrbPointer<int*> myPointer;
int integers[4];
myPointer.ptrForm = integers;
myPointer.intForm += 2; //making it easy to jump by less then sizeof(int)
```

this is working well for me, but i would really love to find a way to make a default member. so that the user does not need to use a .ptrForm after the pointer they wish to use.

Comment: You can't do this (default union member), and I don't see how it helps. If you transmit a pointer value between two machines, the value isn't going to mean anything on the other machine even if they are the same architecture so it sounds like there is something wrong with your data transmission / storage strategy?

Comment: i am asking the receiving machine for the memory address where it will start the block of data, with that information i can compute the pointers on the receiving machine. it of course makes everything unreadable on the sending machine but my goal is to do more of the work on the sending machine because of the very different processors and environments on both machines.

at the moment this problem is only a problem of confusing looking code for the user, i have the functionality working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a conversion operator, along with a constructor, so you can transfer between the types:

```
template <typename PtrType>
union IntPointer
{
    uint64_t intForm;
    PtrType ptrForm;

    IntPointer(PtrType ptr) :
    ptrForm(ptr)
    {
    }

    operator PtrType(void) const
    {
        return ptrForm;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    IntPointer<float*> f = new float; // constructor

    float *theFloat = f; // conversion operator

    delete theFloat;
}
```

That said, I think your treading on thin ground. :|

Comment: Disclaimer: I tried this without a compiler, let me know if something in there goes against the standard.

Comment: +1 Man, I didn't know you can have a conversion operator in a union :)

Comment: this looks like it should do the trick. and i like this better then another suggestion i got about using some sort of keyword to force a pointer out to 64 bytes even on a 32-bit machine (didn't fix the casting trouble).